# UICollectionView sticky header not working iOS 10

Tags: ios10, uicollectionviewlayout

I am having an issue with a sticky header in my collection view not working in iOS 10. I have a collectionView that has a header in the second section only - implemented by setting the size in the first section as CGSize.zero and the size in the second section as the appropriate size:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, referenceSizeForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGSize {
        if section == 0 {
            return CGSize.zero
        }
        return CGSize(width: collectionView.width, height: 80.0)
```

}

I make the sticky header sticky with these lines in viewDidLoad:

```
theCollectionView.delegate = self
theCollectionView.dataSource = self
if let flowLayout = theCollectionView.collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout {
    flowLayout.sectionHeadersPinToVisibleBounds = true
}
```

Everything works great in iOS 11.  When you scroll the collection view up, the header sticks to the top.

However, in iOS 10, this does not work. The header sticks - but not to the top of the screen - it sticks to its initial location and the collection view cells in the second section can be seen scrolling underneath it. There is a gap at the top of the screen. I've attached two screenshots illustrating my problem.  Any help would be much appreciated!

[image: Initial View]

[image: Sticky Header does not scroll to top]

Comment: Update - This has something to do with my view controller being embedded in a UINavigationController.... stay tuned for the fix that I hope to find SOON.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by changing the top auto layout constraint in my storyboard. It was set from the Collection View top to the Safe Area top. Changed from the Collection View top to the Superview top.